# Mapstraction, OpenLayers, LeafLet, etc?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, gis, geocoding

I've been looking through a few different sites and places about geocoding. I currently have a module with Google Maps that I'd like to switch out to a free alternative, like OpenStreetMaps.

However, I've been hearing that these API's are now abstracted away even further, and services like Mapstraction exist that are API-swappable.

However, I haven't been able to find out what OpenLayers really is, same with Leaflet. What are they? Can you swap API's? Do they default to a specfic API?

Answer (score 1):

This article could prove helpful: "A Process for Keeping Pace with Evolving
Web Mapping Technologies. Roth et al 2014" (http://cartographicperspectives.org/index.php/journal/article/viewFile/cp78-roth-et-al/1347)

Especially the table on page 34 (page 10 of pdf) gives you a great overview of the different APIs and their capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a small extension (plugin) to OpenLayers 3 which can use one of the following nominatim provider:

- OSM
- Mapquest
- Photon

It is called [OpenLayers 3 Control Geocoder Nominatim](https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder)

You can see a [demo here](http://rawgit.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder/master/examples/control-nominatim.html).